# comparing angle in measurement for concave mirror

Tags: geometry

From the above picture we can prove easily $ CF = XF$ because CFX is a isosceles triangle. Now if we move the point X  more near near P, it will give the same results(I mean we will get again $ CF = XF$) but by drawing the figure on paper, I have measured that XF= CF are not equal always. What is wrong here?

[image]

Comment: http://www.a-levelphysicstutor.com/images/optics/ccmrrs-r-2f.jpg

Comment: What is the nature of the particular curve? I would have guessed that it’s supposed to be a parabola. What gives you the idea that the curve is accurately drawn?

Comment: if you move the point X more near near P, it will give the same results iff CF=FP..

Comment: why was this migrated to MSE? This is obviously a question on geometrical optics, it belongs here (geometry) as much as it belongs there (optics).

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola#Proof_of_the_reflective_property) you go.

Comment: @newbie: concave mirrors are spherical sections.

Comment: @Physics_guy: Maybe some drawing error. Otherwise it must be fine.

Comment: There is no drawing error if the mirror is cropped from a spherical surface.

Comment: @newbie, try to consider for spherical case.

Comment: If we want the $F$ to stay fixed, the curve needs to be a parabola, and $C$ is not fixed. If we want $C$ to stay fixed, the curve needs to be a circle, and $F$ is not fixed. As $X$ approaches $P$, $PC\sim2PF$ in either case.

Comment: for F fixed we have proved for concave and convex lens  that $f=\frac{1}{2}$ but when we move the incident light ray we get different result!

Comment: @Math_guy: Most lens calculations are approximations. Much depends on the exact shape of the surfaces, the thickness of the lens, and the refractive properties of the material. Calculations for mirrors are much simpler; angle of incidence *equals* angle of reflection. Using this principle, the results are as I've shown in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The geometry in the diagram is true no matter what the figure of the mirror is; that is, $\triangle XFC$ is isosceles. What is not true is that both $C$ and $F$ are independent of $X$. In what follows, $\kappa$ is the curvature of the curve at $P$.

If we wish to fix $F$ independent of $X$, then the curve needs to be a parabola. However, in that case, $C$ is dependent on $X$.

$\hspace{2cm}$[image]

If we wish to fix $C$ independent of $X$, then the curve needs to be a circle. However, in that case, $F$ is dependent on $X$.

$\hspace{2cm}$[image]

Note that as $r\to0$, $PC\to2PF$.